# Update to latest version of java after ppa is discontinued

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, jre

I have been trying to install the latest version of java-8. However, I found out that the [PPA `ppa:webupd8team/java` has been discontinued](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) due to changes in the java licence.

How should I update my java to 8.0_201 or 8.0_211 now?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 .. I installed it by manually downloading the file from java.com then I unarchived the file, and changed the java_home and path. However, is there a repository with the latest version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did search for all PPAs on special [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=oracle-java8-installer).

And it gave some alternatives like [Hellenic Schools Technical Support Team team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ets.sch.gr/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) - they have  [packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Ets.sch.gr/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=java8&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) for Ubuntu

- 12.04 LTS (*precise*)
- 14.04 LTS (*trusty*)
- 16.04 LTS (*xenial*)
- 18.04 LTS (*bionic*)
- 19.04 (*disco*)
- 19.10 (*eoan*)
- 20.04 LTS (*focal*)

You can add this repository and install Java 8 from it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ts.sch.gr/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: doesn't work any more got 404

Comment: @Kid101 what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: For future reference, works for me on `Distributor ID: Ubuntu, Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Release: 18.04, Codename: bionic`.

Answer (score 1):

Either install the Ubuntu Developers package maintainer's version in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install default-jdk` (Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier) or `sudo apt install openjdk-13-jdk` (Ubuntu 19.04 and later) or follow the below instructions for installing Oracle Java from [New Oracle Java 12 Installer For Ubuntu Or Linux Mint (Using Local Oracle Java .tar.gz)](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html). Since that tutorial was published the latest Oracle JDK version has been updated from JDK 11 to JDK 12, and I have updated the instructions from the tutorial accordingly.

1. Create an Oracle account at https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/create-account.jspx and sign in.
2. Download Oracle JDK 12 .tar.gz archive. Make sure the Oracle JDK version you're downloading is the same as the oracle-java12-installer package version. e.g. the installer is currently version 12.0.2, so it can be used to install Oracle JDK 12.0.2.
3. Create a `/var/cache/oracle-jdk12-installer/` folder, and copy the Oracle JDK 12 .tar.gz to this folder.

   For example, create the `/var/cache/oracle-jdk12-installer/` folder and copy jdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz to this folder (from the current directory) using:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk12-installer/
   sudo cp jdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk12-installer/
   ```
4. Purge the old oracle-java11-installer package if you had it installed:

   ```
   sudo apt purge oracle-java11-installer
   ```
5. Add the Linux Uprising Java PPA and install the oracle-java12-installer package to set up Oracle Java 12:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java  
   sudo apt update  
   sudo apt install oracle-java12-installer
   ```
6. This is optional. Use the command below to install oracle-java12-set-default, which makes Oracle JDK 12 default:

   ```
   sudo apt install oracle-java12-set-default
   ```

Answer (score -2):

As you already mentioned, Oracle discontinued providing Java for free. The latest available version is 8. See java.com. If you need a newer version you have to switch to open jdk. To see all avaliable versions, run sudo apt install openjkd-

kibu

Comment: Oracle's Java SE 14 is available for free to download from [download page](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-downloads.html). In January 2019, Oracle released last free update for **Java 8** and still provide that update and newer versions such as Java 11 and Java 14 for free.